# Custom login page with pop up login modal Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, forms, security, authentication

I want to add Spring Security to my project. The way I want this to work is:
On my page, I have static header with "Login" button. When I click the button, javascript piece of code is hiding page content and shows a modal with login form. Currently, "Login" button looks like that: `<li><a href="#" id="menulogin">Login</a></li>`, so basically, it redirect me to the same page. I want to leave it that way, so I won't call a different `login.html` page in `.formLogin("login.html")`, but I will just show a modal with login form.

How to archieve that? - I guess I need to somehow redirect to the same page with modal opened, or do something like automatically perform a click on Login button

main.js

````
var menulogin = document.getElementById('menulogin');
menulogin.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
document.getElementById('login').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('box').style.display='none';
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use `.formLogin("/login")` and handle the request mapping for `"/login"` in your controller to load the same page with modal opened.

Comment: ```/login``` would be a different page in that case, but I want to stay on the same page, and when im doing the mapping that I described, it still redirecting me to login modal.

Comment: /login would be just a request mapping and you can redirect to the modal